# Looking for ranks.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X$ belong to $\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$, where X is inrevertible and let its column vectors be $X_1,X_2, \dots X_n$. Let $Y$ be a matrix that has the column vectors $X_2, X_3, \dots , X_n$. 
Let 
$A=YX^{-1}$ and $B = X^{-1}Y$.

> How do I find $\operatorname{rank} A$ and $\operatorname{rank} B$?

In my humble opinion, the maximum rank can be $n-1$ (since there is no point taking $0$ column into account and both common part is $X_2, \dots , X_N$.

But how can I prove it on the paper?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an exam question?

Comment: This is preparation for exams, i currently have 36/51 and exam is theoretical (and very hard for me, since im very-very bad at theory    (very nervous) - long story short - i MUST collect as many points as i can before the theory (100 defnitions at the exam - i must learn them by heart, since i can't logically understand them unfortunately)

Comment: So you know that $Y$ has rank $n-1$. Have you proved any theorems in class/homework about how you can interpret rank in terms of dimension of some subspaces?

Comment: We haven't done anything remotly like that imo, everything has some real numbers in them and pretty standard, but this is some next level math for me

Comment: So you don't remember something like $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\dim C(A)$ (column space)? I don't have any idea what tools you have at your disposal. The fact is that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ when $B$ is nonsingular/invertible.

Comment: Ok, from conspect i can see rank(a1....ai) = dim(L(a1...ai))

But what is X^-1? Y?

And must i show some real number of theoretical value?

Comment: Because $X^{-1}$ is invertible, the every column of $YX^{-1}$ is a linear combination of the columns of $Y$ and vice versa.

Comment: But is my proof enough? 

In my humble opinion, the maximum rank can be n−1 (since there is no point taking 0 column into account and both common part is X2,…,XN.

There is nothing scientific in it

Comment: You need to ask your instructor, not me. I have no clue what you are supposed to know or use.